# how to access lazy loaded objects from GAE Datastore in google app engine - JAVA JPA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, lazy-loading

i've been struggling with a problem for quite some time and i guess i just don't fully understand yet how GAE Datastore works.

i have the following Entity (i removed code unnecessary for the question)

```
 @Entity
public class Post{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long Id;

//info
private String title;

//comments
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "post")
private List<Comment> comments;

//getter and setters...
}
```

and also the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Vibe vibe; // vibe id

//getters and setters...
}
```

so far so good..  i am using Endpoints, and i already have several functions that work properly, if i want to add a new post, or posting a new comment on a post,
i only have problems when i want to fetch the list of all comments of a specific post - as in to access Post.getComments();

i am using fetch = FetchType.LAZY because in some cases i just want to fetch all the posts in my database without the comments, as in to show them in some kind of an index.

for example when i try this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getPostComments")
public List<Comment> getPostComments(@Named("postId") Long postId) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    List<Comment> results = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    try {
        Post p = mgr.find(Post.class, postId);
        if (p == null) {

            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Post does not exist");

        } else {

            results = p.getComments();
        }

    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return results;
}
```

i get bad request error 400 with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

i tried all kinds of different ways but no luck, and all the solutions i've found were saying i should use fetch = FetchType.EAGER, which i don't want, and honestly it make it seems as if LAZY type is useless.
so obviously i'm missing something! please help! if you could write an example for fetching the list it would be great!

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: hey i updated the quest, basically i just want to know what is the proper way of doing this. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually my solutions was to create a new type of object that didn't have any references to lazy loaded inner object and copy the wanted info to it and then return it.

for this example i did this:
new CommentResults class:

```
public class CommentResults{

private String message;

private Long userId;

//getters and setters...
}
```

my new getComments method would look like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getPostComments")
public List<CommentResults> getPostComments(@Named("postId") Long postId) {
EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
List<CommentResults> results = new ArrayList<Comment>();
try {
    Post p = mgr.find(Post.class, postId);
    if (p == null) {

        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Post does not exist");

    } else {
        for(Comment c:p.getComments()){    //copying the data
            CommentResults cr = new CommentResults();
            cr.setMessage(c.getMessage);
            cr.setUserId(c.getUserId);
            results.add(cr);
        }
    }

} finally {
    mgr.close();
}

return results;
}
```

im still not sure if this is the best solution, having to create a new object and copy information on every request seems like a big task for just one server request, but it works for now, if you know of a more elegant solution please share!